# C++ Creating An Outline Of A Circle Using Multiple Lines

Tags: c++, geometry, trigonometry, lines, angle

I am working on a game and thinking of ways to create a circle outline using only lines.

So I have a graphics function like so

```
void drawLine2D(float starX, float startY, float endX, float endY);
```

this will draw a line from the start 2D coordinates to the end 2D coordinates.

So for example, If I was to call the function like this

```
drawLine2D(0, 0, 10, 10);
```

A line would be drawn from `Vector2D(0, 0)` to `Vector2D(10, 10)`

So I was thinking and I know it is possible to create an outline of a circle using multiple lines so it appears to be a circle. I am just having some problem with the math. This is how I envision my circle outline function to look

```
void drawCricleOutline(float circleCenterPointX, float circleCenterPointY, int circleSize)
{
    //circleSize will scale how big the circle will be
    for(int i = 0; i < circleSize; i++)
    {
        drawLine2D(magicValueX1, magicValueY1, magicValueX2, magicValueY2)
    }
}
```

The trigonometry required to draw a circle outline like this is the part where I am getting stumped... Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Just a note, based on your pseudocode, it looks like `circleSize` will not "scale how big the circle will be", but instead would determine the number of line segments used to draw the circle.

Comment: @0x5453 bigger circles will require more line segments in order to make the circle look proper/smooth curves. But yes I see your point, it was just an example to give people a better idea of what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2):

One possible definition of sine and cosine of *phi* is the *y* and *x* coordinate, respectively, of the end-point of a unit circle arc with angle *phi*. In other words, you're looking for this:

```
pointOnCircle.x = cos(angle) * radius + centre.x;
pointOnCircle.y = sin(angle) * radius + centre.y;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two primary ways to draw a circle. One is to approximate it by *n* line segments by using `x = r * cos(angle)` and `x = r * sin(angle)` over the 0 to 360 degrees (or 0 to 2 Pi radians) in *n* steps. The other (and more commonly done one) is to use the formula for a circle, `x^2 + y^2 = r^2` and draw the pixels from one side to the next. `y = sqrt(r^2 - x^2)` will draw the top half of the circle and it's trivial to negate that value to draw the bottom half. A further refinement is to note that the two quarters are mirrors of each other, so you can easily calculate a single quadrant and then negate the values.